# Convert Emojis to English Meaning PHP

Tags: php, emoji

I receive a string like this:

```
" hello world "
```

Which I convert using pregmatch:

```
preg_match_all('/([0-9#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}\x{00a9}\x{203C}\x{2047}\x{2048}\x{2049}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{2139}\x{2122}\x{3297}\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?/u', $string, $emojis);
```

I get this:

```
"\ud83d\ude03 hello world \ud83d\ude43"
```

But I need the text equivalents like this:

```
":smiley: hello world :upside_down_face:"
```

Here is my resource for English meanings:
http://unicode.org/Public/emoji/6.0/emoji-test.txt

How can I build an efficient PHP function that would perform this translation.

Here is the function I have written so far.  The short code array has about 1200 elements.

function emo($string)
{

```
//Find Emojis In String      
$emojis_cnt = preg_match_all('/([0-9#][\x{20E3}])|[\x{00ae}\x{00a9}\x{203C}\x{2047}\x{2048}\x{2049}\x{3030}\x{303D}\x{2139}\x{2122}\x{3297}\x{3299}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2190}-\x{21FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2300}-\x{23FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2460}-\x{24FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{25A0}-\x{25FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2600}-\x{27BF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2900}-\x{297F}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{2B00}-\x{2BF0}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?|[\x{1F000}-\x{1F6FF}][\x{FE00}-\x{FEFF}]?/u', $string, $emojis);

// Load Emoji Text Short Codes Into Array   
if ($emojis_cnt>0)
{
    $arr_em=array();
    $arr_em["1F9C0"]=":cheese:";
    $arr_em["1F991"]=":squid:";
    $arr_em["1F990"]=":shrimp:";
    $arr_em["1F98F"]=":rhinoceros:";
    $arr_em["1F98E"]=":lizard:";
    $arr_em["1F98D"]=":gorilla:";
    $arr_em["1F98C"]=":deer:";
    $arr_em["1F98B"]=":butterfly:";
    $arr_em["1F98A"]=":fox_face:";
    $arr_em["1F989"]=":owl:";
    $arr_em["1F988"]=":shark:";
    $arr_em["1F987"]=":bat:";
    $arr_em["1F986"]=":duck:";
    $arr_em["1F985"]=":eagle:";
    $arr_em["1F984"]=":unicorn:";
    $arr_em["1F983"]=":turkey:";
    $arr_em["1F982"]=":scorpion:";
    $arr_em["1F981"]=":lion:";
    $arr_em["1F980"]=":crab:";
    $arr_em["1F95E"]=":pancakes:";
    $arr_em["1F95D"]=":kiwi_fruit:";
    $arr_em["1F95C"]=":peanuts:";
    //This keeps going for 1200 array elements

    //String replace Emojis with  Text Short Codes
    foreach ($emojis[0] as &$emoji)
    {
        $em_hex= dechex(mx_uniord($emoji));
        $string = str_ireplace($emoji, " ".$arr_em[strtoupper($em_hex)]." ",$string);
    }
}

return $string;
```

}

Comment: What have you tried so far to build your function, show us the code. This is not a platform for free software development.

Comment: Thanks for responding Webdesigner.  I added my function.  I appreciate the tip.

Comment: This is a good start, just one question: what is working so far and where do you need help

Comment: It is working, but it seems really inefficient.  It takes about 3 milliseconds on average.  I am using this code inside a chat bot so I will be calling on every message.  Just looking to see if I should be using another method to store and retrieve the emoji short codes and whether my recursive string replaces are the best method.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Change the method so you don't have to do it in two steps.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

maybe is that a dirty but simple solution for you

```
$output = "\ud83d\ude03 hello world \ud83d\ude43";
$return = str_replace(['\ud83d\ude03', '\ud83d\ude43'], [':smiley:',':upside_down_face:'], $output);
var_dump($return);
```

result:

```
string(39) ":smiley: hello world :upside_down_face:"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding episch -  You have gotten about as far as I have. There are about 1200 emojis in the set so not sure this is the best method.  I added my code above.  Thanks!